# How can I use sqlite user function api with HikariCP?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, hikaricp

I am using mybatis / hikaricp to access a sqlite database.

This database uses the sqlite user function to extend the database functionalities (via update trigger)

Using this kind of function un sqlite jdbc driver is possible as follows :

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + databasePath);
Function.create(connection, "title_sort", new Function()
{
    @Override
    protected void xFunc() throws SQLException
    {
        result(value_text(0));
    }
});
```

As you can see, we have to use the sqlite drivermanager, that will return a SQLiteConnection wrapper around JDBC4Connection (around JDBC3Connection that implements java.sql.Connection)

The Function.create function checks the connection instance as follows :

```
if (conn == null || !(conn instanceof SQLiteConnection))
{
    throw new SQLException("connection must be to an SQLite db");
}
```

And so here is my question : how can I use this api with hikaricp ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
Connection conn = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
Function.create(connection.unwrap(SQLiteConnection.class),
                "title_sort",
                new Function() {
                   @Override
                   protected void xFunc() throws SQLException {
                      result(value_text(0));
                   }
                }
);
```

The key part being `connection.unwrap(SQLiteConnection.class)`.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't tryied this solution as I yesterday using JPA / Eclipslink failed because the unwrap could not return me an instance of SQLiteConnection. But with HikariCP, your solution works.